# How to set mount option to docker devicemapper folder

Tags: docker

I'm using AWS ECS and running docker container. My security team perform security vulnerability scanning on my EC2 instance and identified below security risk.

> /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/67c68922b781cc6481c1fcbabfa15db43f853df1cc0614d5a3142c0a40900698 partition does not have 'nodev' option set.

Any one know how to set the docker devicemapper mount options?

Comment: I don't think you *want* to set the `nodev` option here.  This is a container root filesystem, and Docker needs to be able to create devices in `/dev` in the container.

Comment: Hi, can explain why set nodev is not recommended as i need to explain that to security team. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I did in my previous comment.  You may simply want to try configuring that filesystem  with `nodev` and see if everything still works.